# How to show different layouts (Activity, Fragment)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I've a **single activity** that changes its appearance (color and text) depending on an alarm. This activity 'dissapears' when the user presses a button and then I perform some background work. Until this point it is working fine but the problem appears when two alarms are scheduled for the same time. Then, only the first layout is shown. What I expect to happen is that **both colored screens** are shown. There are 10 possible colors and I don't wanna implement a different activity nor fragment for each one.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should implement fragments.... How can you expect two Activities to show at a single time? What you want to do is create a single activity and multiple fragments.

Comment: Ok, so then I guess that creating 10 fragments is the best approach...

Answer (score 0):

You can set first layout as `ContentView`,then wait some times and then set another layout as `ContentView` of your Activity.You can use [AsyncTask](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FAsyncTask.html&ei=UKvPVNHaHI_XauG4gjg&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=0ygDkm0edBrs3j1KHiwfoA&bvm=bv.85076809,d.d2s) to use UI Thread after waiting some times in another thread.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that if the user 'dismisses' the first screen, I want the second screen to be seen.

Comment: @rgc92 It is simple,set a listener to listen for user action.If user 'dismiss' the first screen,then set second layout as ContentView.

Comment: It's not as simple as that because I create the Activity from a BroadcastReceiver like this: `activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   context.startActivity(activity);` and if the first screen is not dismissed, the onCreate() method of the Activity is not called again.

Comment: @rgc92 You can call `setContentView()` method any where in Activity.It is not restricted to be in `onCreate()` method.